# How to create multiple ec2 instance across different subnets and Az zones with private ip address

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a slight issue. I have 3 subnet cidr blocks with 3 different az groups. I am passing a list of static Ip address for these instance to get assigned in order. My code however is throwing "ip address is out of range for the subnet" which makes sense because it's just going from ip 0 to the N instance how can i properly make sure the instance gets placed in the proper subnet. I hope my question makes sense and is clear please see the code below thank you all for the help! The code belows creates the instance

```
  ### Start of Radient FID Server ###
resource "aws_instance" "FID" {
  depends_on = [aws_kms_key.aws-wm-wmad-prod] 
  disable_api_termination     = false
   
   count =  var.How_many_FID

  ami                         = var.windows_dc_ami_2016
  availability_zone           = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  ebs_optimized               = var.windows_dc_ebs_optimized
  instance_type               = var.windows_dc_instance_type_FID
  key_name                    = var.Key_Pair_Ec2
  monitoring                  = true
 vpc_security_group_ids       = [aws_security_group.Private01.id]
  subnet_id                   = element(aws_subnet.private_subnet_cidr_blocks_Apps, count.index).id
  private_ip                  = "${lookup(var.ips,count.index)}"                           
  associate_public_ip_address = false
 
  tags = merge(
    {
      Name        = element(var.Radiant_FID_Server_Tags, count.index)
      Project     = var.project,
      Environment = var.environment
    },
    var.tags
  )
```

I have a variables file which i'm passing the private Ip addresses:

```
variable "ips" {
    default = {
        "0" = "10.7.90.79"
        "1" = "10.7.90.80"
        "2" = "10.7.90.81"
        "3" = "10.7.90.82"
        "4" = "10.7.90.90"
        "5" = "10.7.90.84"
        "6" = "10.7.90.85"
        "7" = "10.7.90.86"
        "8" = "10.7.90.87"
        "9" = "10.7.90.88"
      
    }
}
```

##how i create my subnets

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD" {
  count = length(var.private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD) # count = 3

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.default.id #id34odfjdf
  cidr_block        = var.private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD[count.index] 
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones[count.index] 

  tags = merge(
    {
      Name     = element(var.private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD_NameTag, count.index), 
      Project     = var.project,
      Environment = var.environment
    },
    var.tags
  )
}
```

Comment: All those IPs are sequential, so they probably all need to go into the same subnet. Is that really what you want? If you want more help you need to show the CIDR blocks of your subnets.

Comment: I will actually have 30 servers with different subnets that I want them to go into , but i'm trying to figure out how to prevent multiple ec2 instance resource blocks from being created and have TF make sure that the IP being passed will work for the ec2 instance it's trying to create.  I have 3 cidr blocks 

private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD           = ["10.7.90.64/27", "10.7.90.96/27","10.7.90.160/27"]

Comment: You need to create a map of subnets to IPs, instead of just "number" to IP. As you currently have it configured, all those IPs would need to go in a single subnet, but I can't tell you more without seeing your subnet CIDR blocks...

Comment: Sorry i thought i posted my cidr block 

here is the Block Sir 

private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD = ["10.7.90.64/27", "10.7.90.96/27","10.7.90.160/27"]

Comment: I like the idea of mapping Subnets to Ip address. But i guess how do i do that? is it as simple as 

ariable "ips" {
    default = {
        "dctr-ad-sbn-use1-az1a-prod-lan-010" = "10.7.90.79"
        "dctr-ad-sbn-use1-az1a-prod-lan-011" = "10.7.90.80"
}
}
Is this an example?

Comment: Can you also show the code for `aws_subnet.private_subnet_cidr_blocks_Apps` and any variables holding the CIDR blocks?

Comment: I actually got rid of that, it was just another private cidr block all i have now is 3 cidr blocks
private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD = ["10.7.90.64/27", "10.7.90.96/27","10.7.90.160/27"]

Comment: I'm asking to see how you are creating the `aws_subnet` resources, so I can figure out how you would iterate over them.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB i posted on the original question. I'm a rookie with TF learning still so thank you for all the help so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242048/discussion-between-bo-bhayani-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say you have the following CIDR block list defined:

```
private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD = ["10.7.90.64/27", "10.7.90.96/27","10.7.90.160/27"]
```

Then you could define your IP list like this:

```
variable "ips" {
    default = [
        { subnet=0, ip="10.7.90.79" },
        { subnet=0, ip="10.7.90.80" },
        { subnet=0, ip="10.7.90.81" },

        # etc...

        { subnet=1, ip="10.7.90.100" },      
        { subnet=1, ip="10.7.90.101" },      

        # etc...

        { subnet=2, ip="10.7.90.170" },
        { subnet=2, ip="10.7.90.171" },
    ]
}
```

Each subnet number being the index in the `private_subnet_cidr_blocks_AD` list that corresponds to the CIDR block that the IP belongs to.

Then your instance definition could look like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "FID" {
  for_each = toset( var.ips )

  subnet_id  = aws_subnet.private_subnet_cidr_blocks_Apps[each.value.subnet].id
  private_ip = each.value.ip
```

Comment: Thank you this seems like more like it :) sorry about the rokie question sir I just read your BIO VERY IMPRESSIVE ! thank u for the help!

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, why do you need to specify specific IP addresses on these servers? Why not let Amazon assign available IPs based on the subnet?

Comment: I wish I could. I guess they recreate these firewall rules for servers that haven't been created yet and then give me the list of ips. I have mentioned we should let the servers determine the Ips but no one listens to me :(